# ASP.NET Security Exception

Tags: asp.net, веб-программирование, iis, asp.net-webforms, webforms

Создал проект ASP.NET (не MVC). Скачиваю файлы пользователя в созданную ручками директорию "tempFiles". Далее как-то обрабатываю эти файлы и отдаю обратно пользователю.

На локальном сервере все работает отлично.
При публикации на хостинг smarterasp вылазит не понятная ошибка [image: Server Error in '/' Application.]
<sub>(источник: [cs633124.vk.me](http://cs633124.vk.me/v633124618/17635/gdUW9WoweLk.jpg))</sub>

Есть подозрение на способ работы с файловой системой (через физические пути) и возможно хостинг блокирует это действие, если да, то как от этого избавиться?

Может быть, кто-то сталкивался с такой проблемой?

Comment: Дать аккаунту, под которым работает AppPool Вашего приложения, право писать в папку "tempFiles". Как Вы получаете физический путь к этой папке?

Comment: @Igor права выставлены в читать\писать - здесь проблемы не должно быть
Путь получаю через Server.MapPath("tempFiles")

Comment: Попробуйте получить Exception.StackTrace.

Comment: Включи дебаг `<system.web> <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"></compilation>` ошибку станет лучше видно

Comment: @timda в том то и дело, что включен и показывает такую ошибку

Comment: У Вас хостинг в виде выделенной вирт.машины или физ.сервера? Если нет, то почему хостер должен разрешать доступ к физическим дискам?